# How to ignore or exclude backup files [files ending with ~] in shell other than using regular expressions?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, find

For example, If I want to get the `md5checksum` of all files in a path.

`$ find /path/to/ -type f -print0 | xargs -0 md5sum`

But the output also includes checksum of backup files. In general, any way to ignore backup files in shell?

Comment: Why don't you want to use a regular expression in a context where it naturally fits and for which it was specifically invented?

Comment: `find /path/to/ -type f ! -name "*~" -print0`

Answer (score 2):

Just tell `find` to restrict the found names to those that do not end with tilde:

```
find /path/to/ -type f ! -name '*~' -exec md5sum {} +
```

This does not use regular expressions (`*~` is a filename globbing pattern).

Answer (score 0):

The only file name pattern that typically has a special meaning in the context of Unix shell is names starting with dot `.` .These files are typically considered "invisible" for default shell expansion.

Different applications use different name patterns for indicating what they consider to be "backup files" (tilde `~` in the beginning or a name, in the end, `.backup` extension etc.). Unless such applications also mark such files with specific (non-standard) file attributes, the easiest way to tell them apart is by providing a file name pattern or wildcard specific for a given type of backup files.

In your case, `find` accepts file name patterns as a regular argument: `-name "*~"`